# a character string failed conversion to a numeric value

Tags: teradata

I am just trying to add the letter A to the beginning of the results Im bring back and I keep getting this message. 
Query Failed. 3535 a character string failed conversion to a numeric value
Thanks for any help.

```
select
            a.area_cd  as CO_Area 
            , 'A' +  a.area_cd
 from intDDt.DIXX a
```

Comment: you need to cast numeric value in varchar before concatenate.

Comment: SELECT ('VarValue' + CAST(32 AS VARCHAR))

Answer (score 4):

`+` is a numeric operator in Standard SQL and Teradata and **not** a string concat (as in MS SQL Server). You need to use `||` instead:

```
'A' || TRIM(a.area_cd)
```

The TRIM results in an automatic typecast.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

please try this,

```
select
         a.area_cd  as CO_Area 
          , ('A' + CAST(a.area_cd AS VARCHAR))
from intDDt.DIXX a
```

Comment: This is not working outside of SQL Server as  `+` is not a string operator

Comment: I am getting query failed 3707 syntax error, expected something like '(' between the 'VARCHAR' keyword and ')'